# Jquery toggleClass not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am building my own Accordion tab using css and jquery. 
 when a tab is clicked it should be open and any other opened tab should be minimized or closed this is working as supposed to be.

Problem is when opened tab element is clicked it should also be closed/minimized. I am using toggleClass but its not working for closing the same element. Means the default css is not toggling. I had spend lots time in this code but figure out the problem

> For example if div with id2 and class 'open' is clicked it will show the content(Working) and again when it is clicked it should be closed(not working)
>   Here is my code

Javascript code

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(document).on('click',function(e){
            if(e.target.nodeName == "H6")
            {
                var rootNode = e.target.parentElement.parentElement.getAttribute('id');
                var parentNode = e.target.parentElement.getAttribute('id');
                var childN = null;
                for(var i = 0;i<document.getElementById(rootNode).childElementCount;i++)
                 {
                   if($(document.getElementById(rootNode).children[i]).height()>25)
                    {
                     //childN = $(document.getElementById(rootNode).children[i]);
                        childN = $(document.getElementById(rootNode).children[i]).attr('class');
                        $(document.getElementById(rootNode).children[i]).removeClass('pp2');
                        //$(document.getElementById(rootNode).children[i]).addClass('pp');
                        break;
                    }
                }
    //                    alert(childN);
                //var childNode = document.getElementById(parentNode).childNodes[1].getAttribute('class');
                $(document.getElementById(parentNode)).toggleClass('pp2');
                //childN.toggleClass('pp');

               }
           });
       });
    </script>
```

Comment: You're not using jQuery properly. You're mixing up vanilla Javascript with your jQuery, giving you extra work which could be minimized by jQuery itself.

Comment: in document.getElementById(), why aren't you passing the ids as parameters?

Comment: Is `toggleClass` not working, or is it working but not resulting in what you want?

Comment: toggleClass is working but It is not closing the content means its only toggling the class once like PP is default class and pp2 is the class which display the content it is not re assigning div the default pp class

Comment: its is hard to help you without the HTML... best will be if you put this on fiddle, or something

Comment: show me your HTML too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem in the code is while trying to close the opened tab, it removes the css responsible for display content till here its fine but when it exits the for loop below line again toggle the class so the opened tab is closed and again opened.

Defective line of code

```
 $(document.getElementById(parentNode)).toggleClass('pp2');
```

solution is compare the id of clicked element and the element which has to be closed

```
        <script type="text/javascript" >
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(document).on('click',function(e){
            if(e.target.nodeName == "H6")
            {
                var rootNode = e.target.parentElement.parentElement.getAttribute('id');
                var parentNode = e.target.parentElement.getAttribute('id');
                var childN = null;
                var comp = null;
                for(var i = 0;i<document.getElementById(rootNode).childElementCount;i++)
                {
                    if($(document.getElementById(rootNode).children[i]).height()>25)
                    {
                        childN = $(document.getElementById(rootNode).children[i]).attr('class');
                        comp = $(document.getElementById(rootNode).children[i]).attr('id');
                        $(document.getElementById(rootNode).children[i]).removeClass('pp2');
                        //$(document.getElementById(rootNode).children[i]).addClass('pp');
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if($(document.getElementById(parentNode)).attr('id')!=comp)
                {
                    $(document.getElementById(parentNode)).toggleClass('pp2');
                }
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Show me your HTML too.

Comment: <div id="main">
            <div id="id1" class="pp"><h6>id1</h6><div class="hid"><h1>Panel 1</h1></div></div>
            <div id="id2" class="pp"><h6>id2</h6><div class="hid"><h1>Panel 2</h1></div></div>
            <div id="id3" class="pp"><h6>id3</h6><div class="hid"><h1>Panel 3</h1></div></div>
            <div id="id4" class="pp"><h6>id4</h6><div class="hid"><h1>Panel 4</h1></div></div>
            <div id="id5" class="pp"><h6>id5</h6><div class="hid"><h1>Panel 5</h1></div></div>
        </div>

Answer (score 0):

you just use this code:

```
$('#main h6').click(function(e){
    if($(this).parent().hasClass('active')) {
        $(this).parent().find('> .hid').slideUp().parent().removeClass('active');
    } else {
        $(this).closest('div#main').find('.pp.active > .hid').slideUp().parent().removeClass('active');
        $(this).parent().addClass('active');
        $(this).parent().find('> .hid').slideDown();
    }
});
```

and this css also:

```
.hid{display: none;}
```